# About page break of telerik report

Tags: telerik, report

IN Telerik report I have an issue with break page. I have groups on my report. So some pages just display only one grouped item although below of the last row there is a large blank area. I want the next grouped item to be shown below the first item on the same page. Please see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26ElT.png) for more detail.
I want content of report to fill up full page

Please help me solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Most probably the second grouped item does not fit in the same page and this is why it shows in a new page and leave the space in the previous one. Most probably you have set "GroupKeepTogether" and this is why you get the rendering in this way. Have a look at pagination to find out how to manage your report http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/designing-reports-page-layout-rendering-understanding-pagination.html

Comment: Thanks for your link. But I still not find the solution for me. Is someone met the same issue like me? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Table Group Explorer, Group Properties,
make "KeepTogether:  False" in Misc Section

or

In the table property, make "KeepTogether: False" in the Behavior section.